# Nested Loop with Y/N to continue input

Tags: java

I'm trying to ask the user if they'd like to continue by selecting Y or N at the end of the loop.  If they select Y, it should restart the whole program, if N then it should end.  I keep getting errors when I try to do a do-while.

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
public class killmenow2
{
  static int killmenow2;

  public static void main (String args[])
  {
String stringFirstNum, stringNextNum, choice;
final String restart = 0;
double firstNum, numNums = 0, total, accumTotal = 0, average, nextNum;

do
{ 
//user enters first number
    stringFirstNum = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter the first number: ");
    firstNum = Double.parseDouble(stringFirstNum);    //convert string to int

``//Initialize accumulator variable to 0
        for(numNums = 0; numNums>0; numNums++)
           accumTotal = 0;

    {
//user enters next number, begins loop which terminates when user enters "0"
   nextNum = 1;
   numNums = numNums++;
      while (nextNum != 0)
      {
      stringNextNum = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter the next number: ");
      nextNum = Double.parseDouble(stringNextNum);  //convert string to int
      accumTotal += nextNum;
            numNums++;
      }
    }
//Accumulate total of next numbers
      total = accumTotal + firstNum;
      System.out.println("The total of your numbers is: " + total);
//calculate average of numbers   
        average = total / numNums;   
        System.out.println("The average of your numbers is: " + average);
        System.out.println("numnums is " + numNums); 
//user inputs if they would like to continue processing numbers
        System.out.println("Would you like to continue processing numbers? (Y/N)");
        if (choice.equals("Y"))
          restart = 0;
        else restart = 1;
    } //do loop close bracket
  while (restart < 0);

          System.out.println("Goodbye");
        System.exit (0);

    }        
    }
```

Comment: What is this

     `for(numNums = 0; numNums>0; numNums++)
           accumTotal = 0;`

Answer (score 0):

```
final String restart = 0;
```

This is illegal code

and so is this

```
while (restart < 0);
```

A `String` is not the same as a `int`

Try using an IDE like eclipse and read the errors

Answer (score 0):

```
final String restart = 0;
```

REMOVE the `final` keyword. Then change the declaration to

```
boolean restart = true;
```

Then change the logic condition

```
do {
    ...
    System.out.println("Would you like to continue processing numbers? (Y/N)");

***** ADD CODE HERE TO READ THE RESPONSE *****  

    if (choice.equals("Y"))
      restart = true;
    else 
      restart = false;
} while (restart);
```

Even better:

```
do {
    ...
    System.out.println("Would you like to continue processing numbers? (Y/N)");

***** ADD CODE HERE TO READ THE RESPONSE *****  

} while (choice.equalsIgnoreCase("Y"));
```